# Excel conditional nested if

Tags: excel, if-statement, nested, excel-formula

I'm having a little bother with a formula, and am hoping for some help.

So I have an action tracker spreadsheet I use fairly regularly, and i'd like to add a date check function. In one column I have when I'm expecting an item to be completed, and typically i'd compare that with todays date to determine if it is overdue or not. However what i'd like is the following;

If the items status is "Closed" - Do nothing
If the item is "Open" - Compare the resolution date with today, if its overdue mark as "overdue", if it's not due for XYZ days then return something like "due in X Days".

I've had a few goes doing this using nested if's, but just can't seem to crack it!

=IF(G4 = "Closed"; "NA"; IF(F4-TODAY() > TODAY();"Update Required";"No Update Required")) - is what i have so far. G4 is the status of the item (open/closed/etc), f4 is the expected completion date of the item.

Thanks!

Comment: The part `IF(F4-TODAY() > TODAY() ...` looks strange. You'll just need `F4 > TODAY()`.

Comment: Good point actually, was a redundant bit of the formula. I now have =IF(G4 = "Closed"; "Closed"; IF(F4 > TODAY();"Follow Up";"Overdue!")). So if an items status is "Closed", the 'date check' column also shows it as "Closed". If it's Open, and the completed date is overdue shows as overdue etc. Now i just need to include the thresholds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you:

```
    =IF(G2="Closed","NA",IF(F2>TODAY(),"Overdue "&F2-TODAY()&" days","No Update Required"))
```

That will calculate and display the number of days the item is overdue rather than hard coding in numbers.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add some more nested IFs, e.g.:

```
=IF(G3 = "Closed"; "Closed"; IF(TODAY() > F3 + 5;"Overdue for 5 days!"; IF(TODAY() > F3;"Overdue!";IF(AND(TODAY() > F3-5;TODAY()<F3);"Follow-up within 5 days!";"Open"))))
```

Note that I did not include your exact requirements, but that should give you are start.

Comment: Thanks MP24, that seems to have got it.